# How to Collapse code in Twincat TcXaeShell?

Tags: twincat

How can I collapse all code in the text editor in Beckhoff's TcXaeShell.
Standard Visual Studio Ctrl+m, Ctrl+o doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to tools -> customize and click keyboard next to the close button

search for fold in the show commands containing box

select edit.collapseAllFolds and select the press shortcut keys input box

Enter whatever shortcut keys you want to assign and press assign.

You can also assign a shortcut to edit.expandAllFolds to reverse the command